# Group by Id and by alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, postgresql

I have a table with repeated Ids and with a JSON data that represents an alias "players_level", I'm trying to group the Ids so I don't have duplicated Ids but the problem is that when grouping the Ids I can't get the row with the greater "players_level" alias, example I have this data:

| id | score | players | players_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | {} | 0 |
| 16 | 1000 | {"1": {"222": [], "1232": [], "2824": [], "33332": [], "66345": []}} | 2 |
| 17 | 0 | {"1": {}} | 1 |
| 16 | 500 | {"1": {"2824": ["148500"]}, "48": {"2890": []}} | 3 |

And I'm trying to group the data like this:

| id | score | players | players_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | {} | 0 |
| 17 | 0 | {"1": {}} | 1 |
| 16 | 500 | {"1": {"2824": ["148500"]}, "48": {"2890": []}} | 3 |

As you can see the row 2 disappeared because its players_level was 2 and the fourth one has level 3... but when trying to group using multiple techniques with SQL (Group By, Order By, Max...) I can't get the right row to output :(

Can anybody help me please? I have a fiddle link with the data example:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfQVa722kfkNw2JyRdQJZr/0

Comment: Are you trying to group or remove duplicates and retain one with highest id? From your sample output it looks like delete duplicates.

Comment: @Pankaj Yes, I'm trying to remove the duplicates Id but in the duplicated Ids keep the one with the highest player_level.

Comment: Postgres or MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` with a subselect with `MAX`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `players` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `score`, `players`) VALUES
  ('1', 0, '{}'),
  ('16', 1000, '{"1": {"222": [], "1232": [], "2824": [], "33332": [], "66345": []}}'),
  ('17', 0, '{"1": {}}'),
  ('16', 500, '{"1": {"2824": ["148500"]}, "48": {"2890": []}}')
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t.id, t.score, t.players,
  (CASE
  WHEN (JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(t.players, '$."1"."2824"'), '148500') = 1 OR JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(t.players, '$."1"."2824"'), '"148500"') = 1) THEN 3
  WHEN JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(JSON_EXTRACT(t.players, '$."1"')), '"2824"') = 1 THEN 2
  WHEN JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(t.players), '"1"') = 1 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) players_level
from test t  
HAVING (id,players_level) IN (SELECT t.id,
  MAX(CASE
  WHEN (JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(t.players, '$."1"."2824"'), '148500') = 1 OR JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(t.players, '$."1"."2824"'), '"148500"') = 1) THEN 3
  WHEN JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(JSON_EXTRACT(t.players, '$."1"')), '"2824"') = 1 THEN 2
  WHEN JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_KEYS(t.players), '"1"') = 1 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
  END) players_level
from test t
GROUP BY t.id);
```

| id | score | players | players_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | {} | 0 |
| 17 | 0 | {"1": {}} | 1 |
| 16 | 500 | {"1": {"2824": ["148500"]}, "48": {"2890": []}} | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfQVa722kfkNw2JyRdQJZr/0)